# Why is YUI test console ignored when test is used by two YUI instances

Tags: javascript, yui

If I run a test case like this, my test results show up inside the YUI **test-console widget**:

```
YUI({debug: true}).use('test', 'event-base', 'test-console', function (Y) {
    fooTests = new Y.Test.Case({
        name: "foo",
        testFoo: function () {
            Y.assert(5 == 6);
        }
    });    

    Y.on("domready", function () {
        (new Y.Test.Console({
            newestOnTop: false,
            style: 'block'
        })).render('#log');
        Y.Test.Runner.add(fooTests);
        Y.Test.Runner.run();
    });
});
```

If I run the exact same code but create another YUI instance that uses 'test' first, the tests show up in the **browser javascript console** (if it's open).

```
YUI({debug: true}).use('test', function (Y) {

});

YUI({debug: true}).use('test', 'event-base', 'test-console', function (Y) {
    fooTests = new Y.Test.Case({
        name: "foo",
        testFoo: function () {
            Y.assert(5 == 6);
        }
    });    

    Y.on("domready", function () {
        (new Y.Test.Console({
            newestOnTop: false,
            style: 'block'
        })).render('#log');
        Y.Test.Runner.add(fooTests);
        Y.Test.Runner.run();
    });
});
```

Is there a way to get the results to show up in the test-console widget when 'test' is used by another YUI instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/console/console-global.html).

I had to add

```
logSource: Y.Global
```

To Test.Console's parameter object.

```
   (new Y.Test.Console({
        logSource: Y.Global,
        newestOnTop: false,
        style: 'block'
    })).render('#log');
```